# Report on user type on google analytics events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We report to google events but want to divide the event label by user type (A or B).
Is there a way to do it?
I know that in some analytics tools it is already structured.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to create a segment for each user type. Here is a link to
[Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en).

Comment: Hey, thanks but i need to mark that only i know the type of them through my platform. It is not the data that google already has.
Kind of a customized user type.